# Examples of LP problems in irrigate engineering

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming

I need examples of linear programming problems applied to irrigation system.
My idea is to give students many examples of LP applications in the irrigation engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with this specific subject but, do you try googling about that? There are many related papers such as:

- [Developing a model for multi-objective optimization of open channels and labyrinth weirs: Theory and application in Isfahan Irrigation Networks](https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=irrigation%20optimization)
- [Optimization of Irrigation Scheduling](https://www.mdpi.com/journal/water/special_issues/Optimization_Irrigation)
- [Linear Optimization Model for Efficient Use of Irrigation Water](http://Linear%20Optimization%20Model%20for%20Efficient%20Use%20of%20Irrigation%20Water)

And so on. I hope they would be helpful.